# ABX testing — probability that the subject is guessing?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, experiment-design, biostatistics, ab-test

So I was doing some [**A**/**B**/**X** tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABX_test), in which the subject:

- is presented with sample **A**,
- is presented with sample **B**,
- is presented with sample **X** — and has to guess wheter **X** = **A** or **X** = **B**.

E.g. **A** can be an audio snippet with no compression (WAV/FLAC), and **B** can be the same exact piece of music compressed with MP3 at 320 kbit/s.

Having done 100 repetitions with 50 answered correctly, would mean that the person is not able to discern **A** from **B**.

OTOH, if 82 were answered correctly, the difference could be said to be more significant.

---

Now, my question is: **given the subject answered 82 of 100 correcly, what is the probability that they’re (not) guessing randomly**?

---

At first, I thought this would be the same as “what is the probability of getting exactly 82 heads in 100 tosses of a fair coin“, i.e. [image], but when you look at 50 out of 100 case, i.e. [image]… I don’t know.

That would be the probability of getting exactly 50 out of 100 correct, when guessing. But it doesn’t seem to be the probability of you guessing, given you got 50 out of 100.

It seems, that if one got 50/100, the probability of them guessing should be more like… 100%?

Thank you!